# Retornar todos os registros de outra classe em JPA Spring

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa, back-end

Como eu retorno uma lista completa de outra classe, dentro de uma classe?
Eu preciso que dentro da Paciente.java retorne (no findALL que me devolve em JSON) uma lista de todos os registros da classe StatusPaciente.java, sem restrições. Isto é necessário porque o front-end precisa saber  todos os valores (campo ID e descrição) para preencher um lookup para o usuário selecionar o valor que deseja.

Segue o código:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="cad_paciente")
public class Paciente {

 ... (fields)

@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="cad_status_paciente")
private List<StatusPaciente> getListaStatusPaciente;

    public List<StatusPaciente> getListaStatusPaciente(){
        TypedQuery<StatusPaciente>  em = EntityManager.createQuery("SELECT x FROM cad_status_paciente x");
        return em.getResultList();
    }

--x--

public class StatusPaciente {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="ds_status")
    @Size(max=50)
    private String status;
```

Como consigo fazer isso? Qual é a melhor maneira?

Comment: Olá, este é o SO em português, por favor, traduza sua pergunta.

Comment: Obrigado pelo feedback, traduzi o texto..

Comment: faltou o titulo

Comment: Alterado, muito obrigado.

Comment: Ja pensou em criar sua propria @Query no seu Repository?

Comment: @NicolasPereira Consegue fornecer um exemplo simples? Lembrando que precisamos retornar todos os StatusPaciente dentro do JSON do Paciente. É possível?

Comment: Você pode criar sua propria @Query como se fosse uma query em um banco de dados, ai dentro da query você faz um inner join como queira